# Plesk 12 API additional-nginx per subscription

Tags: api, nginx, plesk

Is it possible to set the additional-nginx web-server-settings via Plesk API per Subscription?
As from the docs i only can see this changes can be made per ServicePlan.

The Subscription-User is able to modify the additional nginx parameters over the webinterface - (how) is it possible over the Plesk XML API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see there is no [physical-hosting-descriptor](http://download1.parallels.net/Plesk/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-api-rpc/66643.htm) in API to set or change custom directives for Apache or Nginx

Comment: sadly seems legit

solution right now - edit the limitation-file remote _/var/www/vhosts/system/[subscription_name]/conf/vhost_nginx.conf_